# Check status of services and create a file

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have to check the statuses of 8 services on a windows 2008r2 server.Once all the statuses are RUNNING i need to create a file on the server.
Doing some research i found that the following command gives the STATUS, but when i use this as a .bat file it doesn't work

```
for /f "tokens=2*" "%%a" in ('sc query HyS9FoundationServices ^| findstr STATE') do echo "%%b"
```

Also i want to create a file once these services are RUNNING.

Answer (score 0):

#### When I use this as a .bat file it doesn't work

```
for /f "tokens=2*" "%%a" in ('sc query HyS9FoundationServices ^| findstr STATE') do echo "%%b"
```

In a batch file the above command gives the following error:

```
"%a" was unexpected at this time.
```

You need to remove the `"` characters that are around `%%a`.

Use the following batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('sc query HyS9FoundationServices ^| findstr STATE') do echo "%%b"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.